# Can you save skill points for later levels?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, skills

When you level up you get a degree of skill points equal to your INT modifyer plus whatever your class modifyer is. But are you required to use these skill points when you level up, or can you save them until you level up at a later point? Or will you be forced to use them in a cross-class skill?

And what if you're unable to spend them because somehow you get more than you can spend within the limits of your class and level, can you opt to use them later on, or do the extra points get lost?

Comment: It's impossible to end up with more than you can spend; there are literally infinite skills if you count all the Craft and Profession subskills, and even ignoring that, there are like fifty skills available.

Comment: A character who plans to take levels later in a class with a better selection of class skills or a character who only receives 1 skill point per level yet wants to purchase a skill trick might desire to hold off on spending his current skill points, but I can't think of another situation. Is there context for this question?

Comment: Think a Wizard 5/Rainbow Servant 10/Wizard 5: the RS has less skills than the Wizard (certain Knowledge skills and Decipher Text) but still a few additional ones: for example Diplomacy and Sense Motive.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From [Skills Summary](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/skills/skillsSummary.htm):

> ### Miscellaneous Modifiers
>
> Miscellaneous modifiers include racial bonuses, armor check penalties, and bonuses provided by feats, among others.
>
> Each skill point you spend on a class skill gets you 1 rank in that skill. Class skills are the skills found on your character’s class skill list. Each skill point you spend on a cross-class skill gets your character ½ rank in that skill. Cross-class skills are skills not found on your character’s class skill list. (Half ranks do not improve your skill check, but two ½ ranks make 1 rank.) **You can’t save skill points to spend later.**
>
> The maximum rank in a class skill is the character’s level + 3. If it’s a cross-class skill, the maximum rank is half of that number (do not round up or down).
>
> Regardless of whether a skill is purchased as a class skill or a cross-class skill, if it is a class skill for any of your classes, your maximum rank equals your total character level + 3.

(**emphasis** mine)

Comment: Alright, so if you don't have any skills you want to spend the points on and rather put them into a cross-class skill (or a class skill of a class you multiclassed into) it's going to be cross-class buying... well, I guess that makes sense.

Comment: @ThomasJacobs: you can always check with your GM if she would agree to lift the "cross-class" thing, or even lift it partially for skills you have access to via another class.